# Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0 (Angular2 and php)

Tags: php, json, angular

I am unable to get rid of this problem(s), and I am now basically just jumping around from one problem to the next. I am trying to send a post request to my xampp server, but are unable to make it work. I am following different tutorials to bring it together, but there is a gap that I can not bridge.

Error at the moment `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0`

**Angular component:**

```
onSubmit(Username:string, Password:string) {
    this.httpService.sendData({Username: Username, Password:Password})
        .subscribe(
            data => console.log(data)
        );
 }
```

**Angular service**

```
@Injectable()
export class HttpService {

  constructor(private http: Http) { }

  sendData(user:any)    {
    console.log(user);
    const body = JSON.stringify(user);
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8');
    return this.http.post('http://nlr/api/customer/add',body, {
        headers: headers
    })
    .map((data: Response) => data.json());
  }

}
```

**php code**

```
$app->post('/api/customer/add', function(Request $request, Response $response) {

    $data = $request->getParsedBody();
    $Username = filter_var($data['Username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING); //These 4 lines seem to give a problem
    $Password = filter_var($data['Password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $Other = filter_var($data['Other'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $Leaning = filter_var($data['Leaning'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //$Username = $request->getParam('Username');
    //$Password = $request->getParam('Password');
    //$Other = $request->getParam('Other');
    //$Leaning = $request->getParam('Leaning');

    $sql = "INSERT INTO firsttb (Username, Password, Other, Leaning) VALUES (:Username, :Password, :Other, :Leaning)";

    try{
        // Get DB Object
        $db = new db();
        //Connect
        $db = $db->connect();

        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->bindParam(':Username', $Username);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Password', $Password);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Other', $Other);
        $stmt->bindParam(':Leaning', $Leaning);

        $stmt->execute();

        echo '{"notice": {"text": "User added"}';

    } catch(PDOExeption $e) {
        echo '{"error: {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';

    }
});

?>
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Do you get any error in your browsers javascript console? Also take a look in the network tab what exactly you are sending to the server.

Comment: I've usually seen this when the server returns XML or HTML instead of JSON. Have you checked the actual request and response data in the network tab of your browser?

Comment: Hi, thanks for reminding me to look again in the network tab, seeing an error there and trying to make sense of it. The above error message is however what I am getting in the chrome console...

Comment: Are you getting a 404 error in your error or console logs? Do you have URL rewriting setup? If so, is it setup correctly?

Comment: I get an error `Undefined index: Username in <b>D:\xampp\htdocs\nlrRest\src\routes\customers.php</b> on line <b>63` for all 4 of those lines, I have commented out the original lines, and added those 4 due to answers somewhere else. Are they wrong?  *Updates code to show where the lines are

Comment: Do a print_r($data) to see what indexes are available to use. The indexes are the keys listed in the brackets.

Comment: It says that my Username and Password is "undefined" even though I input a string into both of them before submitting...

Comment: @AlfaBravo what does print_r($data) give you? I am guessing it is either a problem with $request or getParsedBody() not giving you the results you were expecting.

Comment: what is the output of `JSON.stringify(user)`? I assume this is creating a string of an object containing username and password? Try not stringifying it, just pass the object directly.

Comment: @kojow7, ok so print_r gives me Array
(
    [{}] => 
) (So I do not get my data through to the backend)

Comment: also, if you're sending data in JSON format, pretty sure you need to set the content type as `application/json; charset=utf-8`

Comment: So you'll need to backtrack and find out where the issue lies. Using echo and print_r comes in handy.

Comment: Yes thanks kojow7 and ADyson, you guys have already opened me up to some new error finding and it looks to me now that even early on my `data` is never populated, so I will see have far back this goes.

Comment: I'm also not that familiar with callback functions, so make sure you are using that correctly. Maybe nothing is being put into the $request variable.

Comment: @AlfaBravo try my suggestions in respect of the client-side code. If there's nothing in your request data, the problem will be the structure and config of what you are sending.